# Restler 3 - Default value for a parameter blocks ability to pass parameter in

Tags: php, restler

I have a very simple class that derives off of the example "Say" class given on the Restler website. It is as follows:

```
 <?php
class Say {
  function hello($to='world') {
    return "Hello $to!";
  }
  function hi($to) {
    return  "Hi $to!";
  }

  function nothing($to='the ground') {
    return "Looks at {$to} quietly but without saying a word.";
  }
}
```

Because the "hi" function does NOT have a default value for the $to variable it largely works as it should:

```
http://localhost/api/say/hi/Jack
```

returns

> Hi Jack!

Great. The problem is when you have a default value like the "hello" or "nothing" functions then it seems you can't pass in the parameter anymore:

```
http://localhost/api/say/hello          -- WORKS, returns "Hello world!"
http://localhost/api/say/hello/Jack     -- FAILS, returns a JSON error of 404
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

On a side note, I also noticed that if you don't use a parameter with "hi" (which requires that $to be set to something) that it returns a 404 error as well. I'm not sure if that's expected behaviour but it seems like the wrong error message for this kind of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restler 2 worked exactly like you expect, for the above hello method it generates the following routes

```
GET say/hello      ⇠ Say::hello()
GET say/hello/{to} ⇠ Say::hello()
```

But Restler 3 only makes one route

```
GET say/hello   ⇠ Say::hello()
```

This is happening because of smart routing, where we do not map optional parameters to url, so  optional parameters can be passed as a query string

In the case of hi method Restler 2 routes it as

```
GET say/hi      ⇠ Say::hi()
GET say/hi/{to} ⇠ Say::hi()
```

Where as Restler 3

```
GET say/hi/{to} ⇠ Say::hi()
```

Thus making `say/hi` to fail as the required parameter is missing

Reason for doing this is to avoid ambiguity. It is explained here in the [routing example](http://restler3.phpfogapp.com/examples/_006_routing/readme.html)

If you want Restler 2 behaviour for all you API in Restler 3 add the following to index.php

```
Defaults::$smartAutoRouting = false;
```

If you just want to turn off smart auto routing at method level or class level, add the following php doc comment

```
@smart-auto-routing false
```